# How do I check if a file is a SQLite Database in C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite

SQLiteConnection.Open does not throw exception when opening a file that is not a database.

```
private void openDatabase()
{
    sqlite = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + this.filePath + ";Version=3;");

    try
    {
        sqlite.Open();
    }
    catch(SQLiteException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message + e.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

How do I determine if a file is a SQLite Database?

Answer (score 4):

Read the first 16 bytes and then check for the string "SQLite Format"

VB.Net

```
    Dim bytes(16) As Byte
    Using fs As New IO.FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
        fs.Read(bytes, 0, 16)
    End Using
    Dim chkStr As String = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
    Return chkStr.Contains("SQLite format")
```

**Update 2**

C#

```
    byte[] bytes = new byte[17];
    using (IO.FileStream fs = new IO.FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)) {
    fs.Read(bytes, 0, 16);
    }
    string chkStr = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
    return chkStr.Contains("SQLite format");
```

Comment: @Ben you can pass the filepath in the above code and check the returned string, if that contains "SQLite format" then your file is a SQLite database. Please check if this works for you.

Comment: Why are you creating an array that holds 17 bytes?

Comment: @Ben this is because in VB, the size of an array is declared with the array's upper bound, where as most languages(including C#) declare the size of an array by specifying the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 3):

```
    public static bool isSQLiteDatabase(string pathToFile)
    {
        bool result = false;

        if (File.Exists(pathToFile)) {

            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(pathToFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                byte[] header = new byte[16];

                for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
                {
                    header[i] = (byte)stream.ReadByte();
                }

                result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(header).Contains("SQLite format 3");

                stream.Close();
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
```